# Unhandled exception while executing module: The property ''DriveLetter'' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists

Tags: powershell, ansible

The Ansible task that I use to mount ISO images on Windows sometimes fails.

```
    openstack: TASK [Ensure an ISO is mounted] ************************************************
    openstack: An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 54
    openstack: fatal: [10.0.134.144]: FAILED! => changed=false
    openstack:   msg: 'Unhandled exception while executing module: The property ''DriveLetter'' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.'
```

I call the Ansible task like this.

```yaml
  - name: Ensure an ISO is mounted
    community.windows.win_disk_image:
      image_path: '{{tempfile.path}}/en_visual_studio_express_2013_for_windows_with_update_5_x86_dvd_6815614.iso'
      state: present
    register: disk_image_out
    retries: 5
    delay: 3
```

Line 54 in the PowerShell script that backs the ansible task seems to be https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.windows/blob/0f1082c372d4351751de360c1f86728adbd4386a/plugins/modules/win_disk_image.ps1#L54

```
            # ISO, we can get the mountpoint directly from Get-Volume
            $drive_letters = ($di | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

Is the PowerShell script missing a necessary wait/retry to get the `DriveLetter` reliably? Why doesn't ansible retry the mount task, given that I specify `retries: 5`, `delay: 3` in the yaml?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.windows/issues/36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I made mistake in the Ansible YAML. Retry count is ignored if `until` key is not present. Therefore, what I needed to do is the following

```
  - name: Ensure an ISO is mounted
    community.windows.win_disk_image:
      image_path: '{{tempfile.path}}/en_visual_studio_express_2012_for_windows_desktop_x86_dvd_1001986.iso'
      state: present
    register: disk_image_out
    retries: 5
    delay: 3
    until: "disk_image_out is not failed"
```

the following works too

```yaml
    until: "disk_image_out is succeeded"
```

to get

```
    openstack: TASK [Ensure an ISO is mounted] ************************************************
    openstack: FAILED - RETRYING: [10.0.133.179]: Ensure an ISO is mounted (5 retries left).
    openstack: ok: [10.0.133.179]
```

I still suspect that some additional wait loop is required in the PowerShell script that implements the Ansible task, but, in the meantime, I seem to be able to apply a retry in the Ansible YAML script instead.